# c++ get base class object from derived class pointer?

Tags: c++, derived-class, superclass

Suppose I have Derived* derivedPtr;
I want Base baseObject from the derivedPtr;

Base baseObject = *derivedPtr; would create the baseObject with the appropriate Base class member variables?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432683/what-does-slicing-mean-in-c)

```
Derived* obj = new Derived;
base objOne = (*obj) ;  // Object slicing. Coping only the  Base class sub-object
                        // that was constructed by eariler statement.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic casting to accomplish this.

e.g.

```
Base* baseObject = dynamic_cast<Base*>(derivedPtr);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: You don't need dynamic cast for this. You only need it for a cast from a Base to Derived. And since the OP wanted a new Base object, you don't need casting at all. :)

Comment: Ah okay, Thanks. I was taught to err on the side of too much casting, so sometimes I forget when it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's actually called 'slicing', since you just slice off everything from the derived class.