# Cannot pass a variable of my own (non-standard) type to a function

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm writing a program that must normalize audio `*.wav` file.
There is a task "to display header's data": `ChunkId`, `ChunkSize` and so on.

I want to make a function named `display_hdr` (In order to have less code in the main.c file, so it will become esier to read this code). To do this I have to pass this function header's variable (variable of type header) as argument, but it writes

```
functions.h|1|error: unknown type name 'header'|
```

---

***main.c***:

```
typedef struct FMT
{
    char        SubChunk1ID[4];
    int         SubChunk1Size;
    short int   AudioFormat;
    short int   NumChannels;
    int         SampleRate;
    int         ByteRate;
    short int   BlockAlign;
    short int   BitsPerSample;
} fmt;

typedef struct DATA
{
    char        Subchunk2ID[4];
    int         Subchunk2Size;
    int         Data[];
} data;

typedef struct HEADER
{
    char        ChunkID[4];
    int         ChunkSize;
    char        Format[4];
    fmt         S1;
    data        S2;
} header;
```

Header's variable was declared in this way:

```
header hdr;
```

And now, **when I try to pass `hdr` to my function it prints an `error`**:

```
functions.h|1|error: unknown type name 'header'|
```

---

***functions.h***

```
void display_hdr( header hdr )
{
    printf("\n*********************************\n");
    printf("WAVE file's metadata:\n\n");

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr.ChunkID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.ChunkSize );
    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr.Format    );

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr.S1.SubChunk1ID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.SubChunk1Size );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.AudioFormat   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.NumChannels   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.SampleRate    );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.ByteRate      );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.BlockAlign    );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.BitsPerSample );

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr.S2.Subchunk2ID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S2.Subchunk2Size );   /// SAMPLES' SIZE
    printf("\n*********************************\n");
    return;
}
```

So, how to pass a variable of your own (non-standard) type to a function as an argument?

Comment: did you put definition of `header` before your function or included proper header file?

Comment: Note also that passing by value may result in [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432683/what-does-slicing-mean-in-c) due to the variable-length array `Data`.

Comment: @taocp, 1 - function's prototype; 2 - struct header; 3 - declaration of hdr-variable (of type header); 4 - hdr gets data from the file (this works correctly); 5 - THIS function.

Comment: @taocp, for the **1** - function's prototype: `:warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]|`

Comment: @Julian: The compiler needs to see the `struct` definition *before* the prototype.

Comment: re: your query, Julian; it is fine to accept your own answer, if you honestly feel it's the best one. Kudos for wanting to be fair to those who put in effort otherwise, though.

Comment: @Jon, maybe.. But in my case it doesn't help. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"The scope of global variables can be restricted by carefully placing the declaration. They are visible from the declaration until the end of the current source file."***

There is no problem on this subject now ( no warning or error ). I just moved a definition of the struct (type) from main.c to function.c (where a variable `header` of type `hdr` was declared).

**function.h**

```
typedef struct FMT
{
    char        SubChunk1ID[4];
    int         SubChunk1Size;
    short int   AudioFormat;
    short int   NumChannels;
    int         SampleRate;
    int         ByteRate;
    short int   BlockAlign;
    short int   BitsPerSample;
} fmt;

typedef struct DATA
{
    char        Subchunk2ID[4];
    int         Subchunk2Size;
    int         Data[];
} data;

typedef struct HEADER
{
    char        ChunkID[4];
    int         ChunkSize;
    char        Format[4];
    fmt         S1;
    data        S2;
} header;     /* A `header` type created. */

header hdr;   /* After a `header`type was created. */

void display_hdr( header hdr )
{
    printf("\n*********************************\n");
    printf("WAVE file's metadata:\n\n");

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr.ChunkID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.ChunkSize );
    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr.Format    );

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr.S1.SubChunk1ID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.SubChunk1Size );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.AudioFormat   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.NumChannels   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.SampleRate    );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.ByteRate      );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.BlockAlign    );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S1.BitsPerSample );

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr.S2.Subchunk2ID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr.S2.Subchunk2Size );   /// SAMPLES' SIZE
    printf("\n*********************************\n");
    return;
}
```

---

**PS**

Of course I could pass a pointer to a function, but I'd like to pass variable. There is no need to do this thought it is better (economy of memory).

*The problem was because of misunderstanding (poor/bad understanding) of* ['scope'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) *properly.*

**PSS**

Maybe, *Andrew W*'s right in some way, but that doesn't solve current problem. That is quite another type of problem. But it is worth reading too!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to pass a pointer?  Doing so will probably give better performance.  Besides that, make sure the struct is defined before the prototype.  Also, you may want to see [Passing struct to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370047/passing-struct-to-function)

Answer (score 0):

Your code simplified inside the main source-code module behaves as expected...

```
/* your typedef's go here */
/* definition of display_hdr() goes here */

int main( void )
{
    header hdr = {0};   /* near initialization: DO NOT RELY ON THAT */
    display_hdr( hdr );
    exit(0);
}
```

*please note that the near initialization is just for brevity in this particular example, do not rely on it in real code.

This gives the following output...

```
*********************************
WAVE file's metadata:


0


0
0
0
0
0
0
0

0

*********************************
```

**So check that your code uses stuff in their appropriate order**.

On a side note, for performance reasons you may want to re-write `display_hdr()`defining it to accept a pointer to header, like so...

```
void display_hdr( const header *hdr )
{
    /* sanity check */
    if ( NULL == hdr ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "*** NULL pointer argument caught when calling: %s()\n", __func__ );
        return;
    }

    printf("\n*********************************\n");
    printf("WAVE file's metadata:\n\n");

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr->ChunkID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->ChunkSize );
    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr->Format    );

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr->S1.SubChunk1ID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->S1.SubChunk1Size );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->S1.AudioFormat   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->S1.NumChannels   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->S1.SampleRate    );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->S1.ByteRate      );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->S1.BlockAlign    );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->S1.BitsPerSample );

    printf("%4.4s\n",  hdr->S2.Subchunk2ID   );
    printf("%d\n",     hdr->S2.Subchunk2Size );   /// SAMPLES' SIZE
    printf("\n*********************************\n");

    return;
}
```

The sanity check ensures that the function will not crash if it is called with a NULL argument, although `__func__` is a C99 addition. If you are using an older standard it may be available as an extension (or just hardcode the name of the function ;) )

Your `main()` function should now pass a pointer to a header object into `display_hdr()`, or to keep it simple in this example just the address of `hdr`, something like that...

```
int main( void )
{
    header hdr = {0};   /* near initialization: DO NOT RELY ON THAT */
    display_hdr( &hdr );
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: My output in quite good:

`Enter the names of input and output files including file extension:
in.wav
out.wav

*********************************
WAVE file's metadata:

RIFF
27163138
WAVE
fmt
16
1
2
44100
88200
2
8
data
27163102

*********************************`

Sorry, I don't understand about output like: `0 0 0 0 0 0 (and so 
on)` ... 
Is there any reason of such an output?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying here. I was referring to the output of the sample code I demonstrated.

Comment: Oh, I think I got what your comment means. Those 0s at the output of my example, are due to the near initialization of `hdr`. It's a quick hack to set all the fields of the `hdr` variable to their zero values (something like using `memset()` on it). Since `hdr` is a `struct`, the proper way of initializing it would be by listing explicitly the values of all its fields, inside the curly braces: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c99) for some examples (since C99 you may use name-value pairs).

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I'm good with variable hdr. I can accaee to any field (chunk, subchunk and so on ...)  Maybe, I didn't understand you again..?

Comment: In my example, the line `header hdr = {0};` defines the `hdr` variable and initializes its memory to zero's. So the output produced by calling `display_hdr(hdr);` at the next line gives all those 0s on your screen. But this is kinda off-topic, it was just some additional info ;) What's more important imho is to pass the address of `hdr` into your functions (this means you have to re-write them) because it saves you memory and in many cases it also improves speed.